# Reading specific bytes out of a byte array and converting them to hexadecimal representation, using Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I am trying to convert a GUID C++ structure into a string representation of the guid. The GUID structure is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct _GUID {
ul_u_long   Data1;
ul_u_short  Data2;
ul_u_short  Data3;
ul_byte     Data4[ 8 ];
} GUID;
```

I am having a problem with converting the Data4 to string. A description of this structure can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373931%28VS.85%29.aspx. From the description, the first 2 bytes of this byte array represents one group of 4 hexadecimal digits and the next 6 bytes contains the second group of 12 hexadecimal digits.

So, given a guid like this 6B29FC40-CA47-1067-B31D-00DD010662DA, the byte array stores *B31D* in the first 2 bytes and *00DD010662DA* in the next 6 bytes.

So, with this guid as an example, and assuming that I have a variable of type GUID with the name *ulguid*, what I am trying to do is to extract *B31D-00DD010662DA* from the byte array *ulguid.Data4* with objective-c++. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: To summarize, you need the data in an **unsigned char[8]** to be converted to a 16-letter hex string. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is a good summary of what I was trying to achieve. The solution offered by Ferdinand Beyer does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet should work:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

GUID ulguid = {
  0x6B29FC40u, 0xCA47, 0x1067,
  {0xB3, 0x1D, 0x00, 0xDD, 0x01, 0x06, 0x62, 0xDA}
};

// 36 characters for the GUID, plus the zero terminator.
char buffer[37];

sprintf(buffer, "%08X-%04X-%04X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
        ulguid.Data1, ulguid.Data2, ulguid.Data3,
        ulguid.Data4[0], ulguid.Data4[1],
        ulguid.Data4[2], ulguid.Data4[3],
        ulguid.Data4[4], ulguid.Data4[5],
        ulguid.Data4[6], ulguid.Data4[7]);

// Prints: 6B29FC40-CA47-1067-B31D-00DD010662DA
std::cout << buffer;
```

Comment: Use the new `sprintf`-based version since the `ios` thing is lengthy and error-prone...

Comment: Yes, I discovered that. I have implemented the sprintf version and it is working nicely... I have tested it with a lot of different GUIDs and everything looks fine. Thanks for your help.